Nonatomic expression expected for Union operation
I'm fairly new to Mathematica and I'm trying to figure out why this is giving me an error. I'm trying to add a list of permutations in cycle form to another list but Mathematica keeps giving me this error.
Code
permlist = Permutations[Range[1,3]]
cyclelist = {Cycles[{}]}
For[i=1,i<=Length[permlist],i++,Union[cyclelist,Print[PermutationCycles[permlist[[i]]]]]]

Output
{{1,2,3},{1,3,2},{2,1,3},{2,3,1},{3,1,2},{3,2,1}} 
{Cycles[{}]} 
Cycles[{}]
 Union: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in {Cycles[{}]} ∪ Null
Cycles[{{2,3}}]
 Union: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in {Cycles[{}]} ∪ Null

etc...

Even if I remove the Print function it still gives me an error. Why is this happening?

Did you try PermutationCycles /@ permlist ?

The output of "Print" is "Null". This gives you the error. If you want to accumulate the list write:
permlist = Permutations[Range[1, 3]];
cyclelist = {Cycles[{}]};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[permlist], i++, 
 cyclelist = 
  Union[cyclelist, List[PermutationCycles[permlist[[i]]]]]]
cyclelist

{Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Cycles[{{2, 3}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}]}

